# Extract keyword that Word Pattern

Tags: php, regex

I have an string.

```
hi {$USER_NAME} THIS IS THE TEST MSG FOR {$USER1,$USER2,$USER3}
```

I want to extract all the `{$word}` from the string. I have tried to use `str_replace` but its not working.

Comment: `{$USER1,$USER2,$USER3}` does not look like a valid string interpolation

Comment: Sir I just need these word as array

Comment: array('0'=>'{$USER_NAME}','1'=>{$USER1,$USER2,$USER3})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short solution with `preg_mach_all` function:

```
$str = 'hi {$USER_NAME} THIS IS THE TEST MSG FOR {$USER1,$USER2,$USER3}';
preg_match_all('/\s*(\{\$[^\{\}]+\})+\s*/iue', $str, $matches);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($matches[1]);

// the output:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(12) "{$USER_NAME}"
  [1]=>
  string(22) "{$USER1,$USER2,$USER3}"
}
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: Thanks a lot sir.You are Great.

Comment: Sir i m zero in reg_exp and unable to find good tutorial on this. could you suggest me any.

Comment: of course. As for PHP: I would suggest to start with official guide: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php.
As for Javascript: try this tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info. Consolidate your knowledge with expressions. Search and download  regexp sheets:  they are very handy

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'hi {$USER_NAME} THIS IS THE TEST MSG FOR {$USER1,$USER2,$USER3}';
$variableRegexp = '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*';
$repeatedVariableRegex = $variableRegexp . '(?:,\s*?\$' . $variableRegexp . ')*';
preg_match_all('/\{\$' . $repeatedVariableRegex . '\}/', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

The output would be:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(12) "{$USER_NAME}"
    [1] =>
    string(22) "{$USER1,$USER2,$USER3}"
  }
}
```